# pandas Dataframe get print AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ljust'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I don't know Why I am getting a error but I am tired. Why this is happening and how would you fix it?  It seems simple?

my data

```
    hours               x
0   2022-03-23 09:00:00 0
1   2022-03-23 10:00:00 1
2   2022-03-23 11:00:00 2
... ... ...
480 2022-04-12 09:00:00 480
481 2022-04-12 10:00:00 481
```

code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# ... more code that I am not showing. 

dfp.set_index("hours", inplace=True)
# below is the error
print(dfp)
```

The error states

> ...
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ljust'

Comment: We need enough of your code to actually reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the hours columns in a datetime object or timestamp and pandas does not allow these datatypes to be index.

You should try converting the column to string and then set it as index.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
    
dfp['hours'] = dfp.hours.astype(str)
dfp.set_index("hours", inplace=True)
```

If this does not fix your issue, we need more code to be able to replicate the issue as mentioned in comments.